# Slideshow not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

After inserting slideshow into my site and publishing, I am noticing that the slideshow is not rendering correctly.  There are six slides and you'll notice [here](http://realtimehockey2015.zohosites.com/) that after each slide transitions, the transition does not complete itself.  There is less and less of each slide being shown as the cycle completes itself.  The left side of the slideshow is where the issue is.  Thanks in advance for any assistance you might be able to offer.  My code is as follows:

```
CSS

 #slider {
        width: 670px;
        height: 380px;
        border: 0px solid #FFFFFF;
        border-radius: 0px;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        cursor: hand;
        cursor: pointer
    }
    #slider .slides {
        width: 4732px;
        height: 380px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #slider .slide {
        width: 670px;
        height: 380px;
        float: left;
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .MOT160912 {
        position: absolute;
        max-width: 670px;
        margin: 0px;
    }
    .c25322 {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 12px;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        color: #FFFFFF;
        font-size: 16pt;
        font-family: patua one;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: left;
        line-height: 32px;
        z-index: 33;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

HTML

<div style="width: 670px; margin: 0 auto;">
<div style="position: relative; width: 670px; "><div style="position: absolute; right:0px; top:0px; padding: 3px 7px 3px; z-index:99; background-color: #; opacity:0.5; border-radius:7px;"><A style="color: #; text-decoration:none; font-size:0pt; line-height:0px; font-family: arial;" HREF="&#104;&#116;&#116;&#112;&#58;&#47;&#47;&#119;&#119;&#119;&#46;&#49;&#50;&#51;&#45;&#115;&#108;&#105;&#100;&#101;&#115;&#104;&#111;&#119;&#46;&#99;&#111;&#109;" TARGET="_blank">&#83;&#108;&#105;&#100;&#101;&#115;&#104;&#111;&#119;&#32;&#77;&#97;&#107;&#101;&#114;</A></div>


<div id="slider"><ul class="slides">

<li class="slide slide1">
 <figure class="MOT160912">
 <a href="http://www.realtimehockey.net" TARGET="_blank"> <IMG SRC="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Homepage%20Slideshow/HomePage%20Slider%202016/RTHHomePageMarket676x380_zpsxmotlvm0.png">
 <figcaption class="c25322">
RTH Apparel
</figcaption></a> 
 </figure>
 </li>

<li class="slide slide2">
 <figure class="MOT160912">
 <a href="http://www.realtimehockey.net" TARGET="_blank"> <IMG SRC="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Homepage%20Slideshow/HomePage%20Slider%202016/ONEHOCKE676x380_zps8ycqqmxi.png">
 <figcaption class="c25322">
OneHockey Tournaments
</figcaption></a> 
 </figure>
 </li>

<li class="slide slide3">
 <figure class="MOT160912">
 <a href="http://www.realtimehockey.net" TARGET="_blank"> <IMG SRC="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Homepage%20Slideshow/HomePage%20Slider%202016/ScoreStream676x380_zpsn771k9zq.jpg">
 <figcaption class="c25322">
Score Stream
</figcaption></a> 
 </figure>
 </li>

<li class="slide slide4">
 <figure class="MOT160912">
 <a href="http://www.realtimehockey.net" TARGET="_blank"> <IMG SRC="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Homepage%20Slideshow/HomePage%20Slider%202016/918PromoBG676x380_zpszrxzpbnx.png">
 <figcaption class="c25322">
918 Hockey Apparel
</figcaption></a> 
 </figure>
 </li>

<li class="slide slide5">
 <figure class="MOT160912">
 <a href="http://www.realtimehockey.net" TARGET="_blank"> <IMG SRC="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Homepage%20Slideshow/HomePage%20Slider%202016/PlanetHockey676x380_zpst8bedho6.png">
 <figcaption class="c25322">
Planet Hockey Camps
</figcaption></a> 
 </figure>
 </li>

<li class="slide slide6">
 <figure class="MOT160912">
 <a href="http://www.realtimehockey.net" TARGET="_blank"> <IMG SRC="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Homepage%20Slideshow/HomePage%20Slider%202016/YetiHockey676x380_zpstraz1m7s.png">
 <figcaption class="c25322">
Hockey Yeti
</figcaption></a> 
 </figure>
 </li>

<li class="slide slide1">
 <figure class="MOT160912">
 <a href="http://www.realtimehockey.net" TARGET="_blank"> <IMG SRC="http://i1314.photobucket.com/albums/t563/RTH13/Homepage%20Slideshow/HomePage%20Slider%202016/RTHHomePageMarket676x380_zpsxmotlvm0.png">
 <figcaption class="c25322">
RTH Apparel
</figcaption></a> 
 </figure>
 </li>

</ul></div></div></div>

JS

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
    <script language="javascript">
    'use strict';
    $(function() {
        var width = 670;
        var animationSpeed = 600;
        var pause = 8000;
        var currentSlide = 1;
        var $slider = $('#slider');
        var $slideContainer = $('.slides', $slider);
        var $slides = $('.slide', $slider);
        var interval;

        function startSlider() {
            interval = setInterval(function() {
                $slideContainer.animate({
                    'margin-left': '-=' + width
                }, animationSpeed, function() {
                    if (++currentSlide === $slides.length) {
                        currentSlide = 1;
                        $slideContainer.css('margin-left', 0);
                    }
                });
            }, pause);
        }

        function pauseSlider() {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        $slideContainer.on('mouseenter', pauseSlider).on('mouseleave', startSlider);
        startSlider();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Without taking a very in-depth look into it, I believe it's related to your `<li>` having padding and the widths being mismatched. The width of your `<li>` elements are listed as 678 when doing an Inspect Element, however you have the width defined as `670` in your javascript.

Comment: clean up the errors in your code, https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Frealtimehockey2015.zohosites.com%2F you have <!DOCTYPE html> several times in there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

".slide" has 4px padding inherited from li element. So your actual ".slide" width = 678px. Add "padding: 0px;" to your .slide css

Comment: Awesome!  That did it.  Thanks so much for your assistance.  Appreciated.

Comment: Identical to my response an hour earlier without any mention -_-